# Euclidean geometry prerequisites

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have used enrolled in a introduction to Euclidean geometry course, but I have very little experience with geometry, almost none. I have an engineering background so I have taken calculus, linear algebra and differential equations.

I have acquired "Geometry Revisited" by Coxeter. Shall I just start working through the book or is there some more elementary material I should work through first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The nice thing about studying Euclidean Geometry is that it starts with a set of axioms, which you'll learn or relearn in the course, and then builds from there. Very very little is required in the way of prerequisites.

Judging from the classes you *have* taken, you are more than prepared to undertake the course. The text you've acquired sounds well-suited for your purposes, if you'd be more comfortable getting an "overview" of what you'll encounter, but please **don't** feel the need to have that material mastered *before* you start the course, and I trust there is no need for you to work through any material more elementary than that.

If you'd like to, feel free to review the [Khan Academy's videos and tutorials on Geometry](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry), which will help you "clear the cobwebs", so to speak, to refresh material you likely covered prior to college.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly speaking, you do not need any particular prerequisites for studying Euclidean Geometry. It is self-contained as it starts with set of axioms (or postulates) and the whole theory is built upon those axioms. Apart from Coxeter's classic you can also have a look on Four Pillars of Geometry by John Stillwell.